# Ssd usage shows 100 percent for 0.1 Mb/s

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, operating-systems, hardware-raid

I have searched this question a lot but all were saying, need to upgrade to ssd. But I have m.2 ssd and I have that problem, I also have two hdd connected to sata, primary os is in ssd. 100  disk usage for 0.1 mb/s is showing in ssd not hdd. Although I removed hdd and restarted it but it was dead slow. Still after removing it didn't get fixed but when I install os fresh in ssd then everything is fine for hours but this problem occurs after some hours of usage, I installed os 3 times, everything is good at start. Ssd is working fine! But dont know what the problem is.

Please someone help.

Comment: **m**b/s or **M**b/s ? mb is millibit, Mb is Megabit.

Comment: Ok my bad. It's Mb. Is there any solution u know?

Answer (score 2):

You may check the drive SMART values to rule out a hardware fault.

**Usually hardware manufacturers tell you the drive speed for the best possible workload.** In general SSD IO isn't just limited by bit rate, but also by IOPS. The use of random or sequential read/write has an impact, too (even on SSDs).

This means it's way slower to read thousand files with each file being 1KB small compared to reading one large 1MB file. **On an older drive with an older SSD controller a high IOPS workload** (could be Windows Search indexing, as you mention it starts after a few hours) **may easily cause havoc, resulting in a massive bit rate decline while maintaining high drive utilization.**

Comment: But all products are new nothing is older. Below is my system specs:                                   b450m max pro, ryzen 3 3300x, ram 16gb ddr4,wb m2 ssd and 10 years old hdd.

Comment: @Titan age of the drive doesn't mean much. If the drive is dead, it's dead. All symptoms point to the drive.

Comment: Hey actually i removed a drive and only the old disk drive and ssd is in the system, its been 4 days, there is no problem...will let you know if this works.

Comment: Hey I forgot to mention, I removed all hard disk and rebooted, only ssd with os there, still the issue was there, now i can say its not related to hdd right ?I reinstalled os and its working good(for now).

Answer (score -1):

Go to advanced power setting and try changing PCI express Link state power management to off. Maximum power savings can cause 100 percent disk usage on NVME Solid State Drives. Because NVME protocol uses PCI express. Here is a smilar post with more information: [SSD disk active time 100 percent frequently on idle](https://superuser.com/questions/1818465/ssd-disk-active-time-100-percent-frequently-on-idle)

Comment: It’s inappropriate to submit multiple answers, pointing to an answer, you believe answers another question. If you believe that flag the question as a duplicate. Answers that contain a summary of the contents of your own answer, will continue to be negatively received, and will potentially be flagged as requiring moderator intervention based on the number of times it happens. I would normally flag as a duplicate, but I don’t feel that answer, is necessarily relevant to unanimously close this question as a duplicate.